# Converation between object ** to object*

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, pointers, type-conversion

I would like to know why my variable it type of pointer to pointer (**)
and not just 1 pointer.

The error is:

> cannot convert ‘Monomial**’ to ‘Monomial* const’ in return

Why is that so?

My Header file:

```
class Polynomial
{
private:
    Monomial * poly_array [];
    int poly_counter;

public:
    Polynomial();
    ~Polynomial();
    Monomial * const getPoly_array();
}
```

My cpp of Polynomial file looks like that:

```
Monomial * const Polynomial::getPoly_array()  {
    return poly_array;
}
```

I have another header and cpp files of Monomial Object.

```
class Monomial
{
private:
        int coeff;
        int exp;

public:
    Monomial(int coeff, int exp = 0);
    Monomial();
    int GetCoeff();
    int GetExp();
    //Operator Overloading
    void operator += (const Monomial& monomial);
    Monomial operator *(const Monomial& monomial1);

    void operator *=(const Monomial& monomial);

    bool operator ==(const Monomial& monomial);
    //Neagative the monomial
    void negate();

    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Monomial& m);

    char* stringRepresentation() const;


};

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Monomial& m);
```

Comment: You should not work with pointers here at all. Just store you monomials inside a `std::vector<Monomial>`

Comment: What do you think `Monomial * poly_array [];` does? What do you think `sizeof(Polynomial)` would be if it just contained this?

Answer (score 0):

There is another problem, besides the one that the error shows you:

```
Monomial * poly_array [];
```

This declaration is ill-formed in C++. The square brackets mean that you declared an array. However, you did not specify a size for the array. You cannot declare member arrays of indeterminate size.

In C (since C99) it would have been a valid declaration of a "flexible array member" (EDIT: although as pointed out, it would have had to be the last member). While such declaration is ill-formed in standard C++, some C++ compilers allow it as a language extension.

I'm going to assume that you have managed to overcome these problems and that `poly_array` is a a well-formed array of `Monomial*` since that's what your error message implies.

---

> I would like to know why my variable it type of pointer to pointer (**) and not just 1 pointer.

In C++ (and also C) you can not return array (nor pass them as an argument to a function) by value. When used in such context, the identifier is implicitly converted to a pointer to the first element of the array. This conversion is called array "decaying".

The type of each object in the array is `Monomial*` so a pointer to such object is `Monomial**`. This is why the return expression has the type `Monomial**`, which conflicts with the type `Monomial* const` that you declared because one can not be implicitly converted to another. The type system saved you from doing a silly thing.

---

I suspect that you intended `poly_array` to be an array of `Monomial` objects instead. You could declare such array like this:

```
Monomial  poly_array[number_of_elements];
//      ^ Note the lack of *
```

`number_of_elements` must be known at the time of compilation. If that is not appropriate for your case, you should use `std::vector<Monomial>` instead.

---

PS. Declaration `Monomial * const getPoly_array()` is equivalent to `Monomial * getPoly_array()`. The `const` has no effect.

Comment: Doesn't a flexible array member need to be the last data member?

Comment: @aschepler good point. There appears to be other syntax errors as well; I suppose OP didn't quite manage to create a mcve.